# YouTube API: Example YouTube Playlist Code?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'd like to create a playlist that loads all the videos a specific user has uploaded.

I was suggested to use the following code (assuming the account to pull in is YouTube):

```
loadPlaylist( { listType: 'user_uploads', list: 'youtube' } );
```

I have looked over the API pages as well: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

But I can't find an actual example code that uses load playlist. Being completely new to YouTube API I have no idea what type of wrapper code I need to make the above work. Something like this (of course I'm missing parts):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
loadPlaylist( { listType: 'user_uploads', list: 'youtube' } );
</script>
```

Or if someone could provide working example with the original loadplaylist line that would be great, and I can work on the other details I need on my own from there.

Comment: I think this should be on StackOverflow instead of StackApps. I've flagged for migration, no need for you to ask again on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Was on Stackoverflow but looked in the footer and say a StackOverflow site for "api/apps" and since this is an api question, this would be the right site no?

Comment: StackApps is for questions related to the StackExchange/StackOverflow API/apps, not just generic APIs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure looking at your snippet, but it appears you don't identify the player object to load. The object syntax is:

```
player.loadPlaylist({list:String,
                     listType:String,
                     index:Number,
                     startSeconds:Number,
                     suggestedQuality:String}):Void
```

Here is the YouTube link with more detail info on cueing and loading playlist:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to embed the videos, you could use:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=USERID
```

And the USERID is your youtube user id with 'UU' appended.

For example, if your user id is `TlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg` then you should put `UUTlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg`. 
If you only have the channel id (which you can find in your channel URL) then just replace the first two characters (`UC`) with `UU`.

So in the end you would have an URL like this:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=UCTlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg`

BTW. you can append `&index=2` to specify which video should be played.

> See answer on [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31051589/4489917)