# Embedding most recent YouTube video with Channel ID

Tags: html, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am building a website for a friend and I'm having some trouble with the YouTube player API. This is the embed HTML IFrame I have so far:

```
<body>    
    <iframe style="max-width: 480px" width="100%" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=UCvDJ_vg2dics1kmwUPnTo_A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
```

This does not work due to the fact that his YouTube channel uses the new ID system and it doesn't detect that in the "user_uploads" type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is stated in the [Player Parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) of Iframe API that the [**list parameter**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#list), in conjunction with the **listType parameter**, identifies the content that will load in the player.

> - If the **listType** parameter value is **user_uploads**, then the **list** parameter value identifies the YouTube channel whose uploaded videos
>     will be loaded.

It is not stated here that you need to place Channel ID in the list parameter. The list parameter value identifies the YouTube channel whose uploaded videos will be loaded.

So what you need to place here is the **USER NAME**.

example

```
https://www.youtube.com/user/Nightblue3
```

Try to use the **Nightblue3** here in the `list parameter` of your request. And your embed video will work.

For more information, check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267426/html-auto-embedding-recent-uploaded-videos-from-a-youtube-channel).

Answer (score 9):

With new channels, that do not have a username, you should use:

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=USERID
```

And the USERID is your youtube user id with 'UU' appended.

For example, if your user id is `TlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg` then you should put `UUTlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg`. 
If you only have the channel id (which you can find in your channel URL) then just replace the first two characters (`UC`) with `UU`.

So in the end you would have an URL like this:

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=UCTlQ5niAIDsLdEHpQKQsupg`

BTW. you can append `&index=1` to specify which video should be played.

> See answer on [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31051589/4489917)

Comment: Thank you. I will take this into account next time! :)