# Embed YouTube channel in website

Tags: php, iframe, youtube, embed

I've been doing a lot of searching, and found many examples, but can't get this to work. I am creating a website that will allow users to register and include their YouTube channel. What I am having trouble with, is having the channel work on the page.

I have tried:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/+lastest?list=UCJ4o9E2dPjSHT6IUb8lvLuA"  width="780px" height="420px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=user_uploads&list=UCJ4o9E2dPjSHT6IUb8lvLuA" width="780px" height="420px" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

I went into my YouTube settings - advanced, and got my YouTube Channel ID, but it didn't work. I also tried my YouTube User ID on the off chance that would work. However, with each one, I just get "An error occurred. Please try again later. (Playback id: xxxxxxx) The playback id is different everytime, so not sure if that is needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Darth Mikey D

Comment: please provide actual link working on youtube

Comment: Do you mean to put the link to the youtube channel in the iframe? I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: no just give me the link of your youtube video that is on youtube

Comment: It's not a single video, I'm trying to embed my YouTube channel.

Comment: Ok, so I kind of got this working. I created a playlist, and put that id in the iframe element, and it worked. I would like to include channels without having to do a playlist, though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested, I found the answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301196/embedding-most-recent-youtube-video-with-channel-id

Not sure why they made that change, but at least I finally found the answer. Only took me a week to finally find exactly what I needed to search for.